# Display my bandwidth connection

Tags: java, swing, bandwidth

I need to display on my java frame my bandwith every X time, but i don't know how to do it, ping only gives me reachability but not bandwidth... I need to "download" something to get the speed but I don't know how... Thanks!

Comment: Why not `Desktop#open()` one of those internet speed test web sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ping gives you enough details to calculate bandwidth

for the below ping command

```
> ping google.com
```

output :

```
Reply from 216.58.197.46: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=56
Reply from 216.58.197.46: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=56
Reply from 216.58.197.46: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=56
Reply from 216.58.197.46: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 216.58.197.46:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 25ms, Maximum = 26ms, Average = 25ms
```

Average Time taken to transmit 32 bytes of data is 25ms

Therefore

bandwidth = (32/25) bytes/ms = ( 32*8 / 0.025 ) bps = 10240 bps = 10240 / 1024 kbps = 10 kbps

Hope this is useful to you.

Comment: Are you using 0.001 b/s because 25ms, no? for me is 30ms how can i calculate?

Comment: sorry I did a mistake in my calculation. I just edited the values.

Comment: if 30 ms for 32 bytes, (32/30) bytes / ms = ( (32*8) / (0.001 *30) ) bps

Comment: And how can I get the speedtest value? I made ping to google and i take that:
    Respuesta desde 74.125.206.94: bytes=32 tiempo=29ms TTL=46

Answer (score 0):

Better use `ping -l 1024 google.com` so the discrepancy of the tcp connect isn't to high.

Also notice that ping can only give you the upload speed.